# Nested Objects in JSON Array return values for onlye first item

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-object

I have an array of employees. when i map trough this array and retrieve values of objects using dot notation everything works fine for top level objects but sub objects return value for `employee.jobtitle.jobdesc` of only first object.

All remaining objects records for `employee.jobtitle.jobdesc` are empty. Below is array. i am using map.employees method to iterate through array and rendering output using ( {employee.id} {employee.firstname} {employee.lastname} and {employee.jobtitle.jobdesc}. Why nested objects are only returning output for only first object e.g. Edward whereas for other Salesman it is not returning anything.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Bob",
        "gender": "Male",
        "nationalId": 1212121212,
        "jobtitle": {
            "id": 1,
            "jobdesc": "General Manager"
        }
    },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "Edward",
        "lastname": "Rick",
        "gender": "Male",
        "nationalId": 1212121212,
        "jobtitle": {
            "id": 2,
            "jobdesc": "Salesman"
        }
    },
        {
        "id": 3,
        "firstname": "Mike",
        "lastname": "Arther",
        "gender": "Male",
        "nationalId": 1212121212,
        "jobtitle": {
            "id": 3,
            "jobdesc": "Sales"
        }
    },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "firstname": "Nick",
        "lastname": "Johns",
        "gender": "Male",
        "nationalId": 1212121212,
        "jobtitle": {
            "id": 4,
            "jobdesc": "Salesman"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses Array map(). You can read more about it in the link below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
const employees = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Bob",
        "gender": "Male",
        "nationalId": 1212121212,
        "jobtitle": {
            "id": 1,
            "jobdesc": "General Manager"
        }
    },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "Edward",
        "lastname": "Rick",
        "gender": "Male",
        "nationalId": 1212121212,
        "jobtitle": {
            "id": 2,
            "jobdesc": "Salesman"
        }
    },
        {
        "id": 3,
        "firstname": "Mike",
        "lastname": "Arther",
        "gender": "Male",
        "nationalId": 1212121212,
        "jobtitle": {
            "id": 3,
            "jobdesc": "Sales"
        }
    },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "firstname": "Nick",
        "lastname": "Johns",
        "gender": "Male",
        "nationalId": 1212121212,
        "jobtitle": {
            "id": 4,
            "jobdesc": "Salesman"
        }
    }
];
    
const allJobs = employees
.map(employee => employee.jobtitle.jobdesc);

console.log(allJobs);
```

Comment: Bro this is what i am already doing. but the problem is it gives a set not list. if there is any duplicate value e.g. one department is associated with 2 employees it only displays first one and next it shows as undefined. in this case there are 2 finance managers but it shows 4th object as undefined. 

["Finance Manager", "IT Manager", "HR Manager", undefined, "General Manager", "Sales Manager"]

Comment: Can you update the json in the question with the scenario that causes undefined?

Comment: Thank you for your support. Issue was in backend configuration. in relationships creation. It is solved now. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

#### React example

```js
const employees = [{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Bob",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationalId": 1212121212,
    "jobtitle": {
      "id": 1,
      "jobdesc": "General Manager"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstname": "Edward",
    "lastname": "Rick",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationalId": 1212121212,
    "jobtitle": {
      "id": 2,
      "jobdesc": "Salesman"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstname": "Mike",
    "lastname": "Arther",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationalId": 1212121212,
    "jobtitle": {
      "id": 3,
      "jobdesc": "Sales"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstname": "Nick",
    "lastname": "Johns",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationalId": 1212121212,
    "jobtitle": {
      "id": 4,
      "jobdesc": "Salesman"
    }
  }
];

const PersonList = () => {
    return employees.map(employee => (
    <div key={employee.id}>
      <h2>{employee.firstname} {employee.lastname}</h2>
      <h3>{employee.jobtitle.jobdesc}</h3>
      <hr />
    </div>
  ))
}

ReactDOM.render(<PersonList />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

</div>
```

#### Vanilla JavaScript example

```js
const employees = [{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Bob",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationalId": 1212121212,
    "jobtitle": {
      "id": 1,
      "jobdesc": "General Manager"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstname": "Edward",
    "lastname": "Rick",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationalId": 1212121212,
    "jobtitle": {
      "id": 2,
      "jobdesc": "Salesman"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstname": "Mike",
    "lastname": "Arther",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationalId": 1212121212,
    "jobtitle": {
      "id": 3,
      "jobdesc": "Sales"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstname": "Nick",
    "lastname": "Johns",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationalId": 1212121212,
    "jobtitle": {
      "id": 4,
      "jobdesc": "Salesman"
    }
  }
];

const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');

employees.forEach(employee => {
  const empDiv = document.createElement('div');
  empDiv.setAttribute('id', employee.id);

  const empH2 = document.createElement('h2');
  empH2.innerText = `${employee.firstname} ${employee.lastname}`;
  empDiv.append(empH2);

  const empH3 = document.createElement('h3');
  empH3.innerText = employee.jobtitle.jobdesc;
  empDiv.append(empH3);

  const divider = document.createElement('hr');
  empDiv.append(divider);

  appDiv.append(empDiv);
});
```

```html
<div id="app">

</div>
```